# Excel VBA: Move name for multiple sections

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I have an unfortunate  data set built up like this, and I need the "Name:" (Firstname Lastname) to be moved to the right side of each product cost, no matter how many entries there are somehow, but cannot figure out the logic to doing so automatically (VBA):

..the title "Name" also needs to be next to  the word "Cost"..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub code()
'Define variables
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range

'Find non-empty cells in column B
Set rng = Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

'move each non empty cell from column B by 2 rows and 4 columns
For Each cell In rng
    cell.Cut Range(cell.Offset(2, 4).Address)
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Not exact, but it does the trick. The rest is not easy to clean up I think.